# DatagridViewAutoFilter en Ingles/Español (Me sale en Chino)

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Me he bajado del NuGet el DataGridViewAutoFilter, pero me salen caracteres Chinos y no encuentro la manera de configurarlo para Ingles o Español
Si alguien ha trabajado con esta clase y sabe como configurarlo le agradeceria la ayuda

Comment: Prueba a descargarlo desde [aqui](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23459) en lugar de la versión del Nuget

Comment: Veelicus, ¿has podido resolver este problema?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave Si, con la version que indica Pikoh mucho mejor.

Comment: @Veelicus, te recomiendo por favor publicar una respuesta para que la pregunta no siga apareciendo en la lista de "preguntas sin respuesta". Un saludo.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave añadido, gracias por la sugerencia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede obtener en ingles en el siguiente Link:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23459

Comment: Recuerda [aceptar tu propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Gracias.